# Triangle Sides Input Output Angles for Non-Right Triangles

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

I'm trying to write a method which will take an input of the three side lengths and give back the angles in degrees. It uses the law of cosines solved for the angle opposite c, and I switch the sides, so it can find the second angle. However, the program doesn't output any of the correct angles. For instance, I input the side lengths 6, 7, and 8, and it gave me 55.51, 44.28, and 80.21. However none of the angles in a 6 - 7 - 8 triangle match those. Here is the method I used:

```
double angleNo(double a, double b, double c)
{
   double calc = Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((a*a + b*b - c*c)/(2*a*b)));
   double s = calc*100;
   double r = Math.round(s);
   double e = r/100;
   return e;
}
```

Also, if it's of any help, here is where it's executed:

```
        angleOne = pull.angleNo(op1, op2, hypo);
        angleTwo = pull.angleNo(op2, hypo, op1);
        angleThree = 180 - angleTwo - angleOne;

    }

     System.out.println("The angles are " + angleOne + "°, " + angleTwo + "°, " + angleThree + "°.")
```

Any help would be lovely, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula is

[image]

So change

```
Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((a*a + b*b - c*c)/2*a*b));
```

to

```
Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((a*a + b*b - c*c)/(2*a*b)));
                                           ^     ^
```

(Otherwise you're dividing by `2` and multiplying by `a*b`, while you want to divide by `2*a*b`.)

I suggest you *don't* try to round the value inside the method. Let it be a `double` until you need to print the value, and then you print it using for instance

```
System.out.printf("Value: %.2f%n", yourDouble);
```

Comment: Thanks, that definitely changed the result, but it's still not displaying the correct result. I also posted the place where it's executed if that helps.

Comment: Please provide values for which it returns the wrong result.

Comment: Input: op1 = 6, op2 = 7, hypo = 8 Output: 55.51°, 44.28°, 80.21°.

Comment: Those three are almost the same length, so it should yield around 60 degrees. The function returns `75.52` degrees which seems reasonable to me. Are you sure it's the wrong value?

Comment: Where did you get 75.52? My output was 55.51, 44.28, and 80.21.